# How to embed pixelbark.com videos

Tags: video, iframe

I have tried embedding some videos from http://pixelbark.com using there embed/share code, the code looks something like this for this url http://pixelbark.com/639

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://pixelbark.com/e/639" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

so all they are doing is replacing com/ with com/e/

This however is not working. Can somebody help me out with this

Comment: Well, you should contact them direclty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually go to `http://pixelbark.com/e/639` you will see that their server throws and error. I suggest you report this issue to pixelbark, it doesn't look like you are doing anything wrong or that there is anything else you can do about it.

Comment: I dont think they have a link where I can report this issue :(

Comment: Comment on their facebook account or other social account.